# How can I load Baidu basemap tiles with mapboxgl?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to load Baidu basemap tiles with mapboxgl, but due to the problem of the coordinate system, there is a serious offset of the tiles. what should I do?

```
let simple = {
      'version': 8,
      'sources': {
        'source': {
          'type': 'raster',
          'tiles': ['http://online0.map.bdimg.com/tile/?qt=tile&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&styles=sl&v=017&udt=20130712'],
        }
      },
      'layers': [
        {
          'id': 'layer',
          'type': 'raster',
          'source': 'source',
          'minzoom': 0,
          'maxzoom': 18,
          'interactive': true
        }]
    }
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2h5eXpsMDgwOSIsImEiOiJjanAxemEyYnQwMWZvM3Fudzh5c3ZvbHJqIn0.j2i8D_Gcam955rcEt2k_mA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', 
    center: [-74.50, 40],
    zoom: 9 
});
```

Comment: There are already some open (that is, cracking) algorithm for solving this shift problem.

Comment: thank you very much ！I did not find it. Can you provide a link or demo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China